# Using Active Record Base Connection to Pull data from Multiple Servers

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a small Rails 4.2 app which is basically a glorified metrics app.  I want to be able to create metric records based off of a few class methods.

The problem is, I need to pull the data from multiple production servers into this one server and I'm not sure on how to do that using AR Base Connection.

Here's my target (metric server) methods in the Metric Class:

```
class Metric < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.last_year_mtd
    m = Metric.new
    m.agency_name = Figaro.env.agency_name
    m.metric_type = "Last Year MTD"
    sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select sum(dst_amt::DECIMAL) from distributions where dst_code like 'COL%' and dst_posted_date::DATE BETWEEN (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '13 Month') and (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '366 Day')")
    total = sql[0]["sum"].to_s
    m.amount = total
    m.save
  end

  def self.last_month
    m = Metric.new
    m.agency_name = Figaro.env.agency_name
    m.metric_type = "Last Month"
    sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select sum(dst_amt::DECIMAL) from distributions where dst_code like 'COL%' and dst_posted_date::DATE BETWEEN (select (date_trunc('month', current_date)) - INTERVAL '1 Month') and (select date_trunc('month', now())::date - 1)")
    total = sql[0]["sum"].to_s
    m.amount = total
    m.save
  end

  def self.current_month
    m = Metric.new
    m.agency_name = Figaro.env.agency_name
    m.metric_type = "Current Month"
    sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select sum(dst_amt::DECIMAL) from distributions where dst_code like 'COL%' and dst_posted_date::DATE BETWEEN (select (date_trunc('month', current_date))) and NOW()::DATE")
    total = sql[0]["sum"].to_s
    m.amount = total
    m.save
  end
end
```

So when I have built this class and tested it in a source server (one I'm trying to pull metrics from) all of these methods work properly and create the metrics since I'm pulling from the local database.

The problem is I have like 8 production servers to pull this data from, execute the SQL on, and create records from.

How would I go about doing this on the metric server.  I'm assuming I'll need to setup all 8 server's postgres info in database.yml and name them each something unique (like acme, johnson, joe, etc).  But in my class and methods, how do I call out to all 8 servers using a block and iterated over each one creating a new metric record for each server and storing it to the local metric model/database?

I'm vaguely familiar with AR abstract so I'm not sure if this is what I need or if there's a simpler way to do it that I'm not seeing in my research.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by reading this post I made earlier in the month and using an abstract AR model to facilitate communication with the reporting/metric server.

[Getting Information from another Rails Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763634/getting-information-from-one-rails-server-to-another)